# How to read Netty Logs

Tags: java, netty

I was wondering what this

- [nioEventLoopGroup-2-2]
- [nioEventLoopGroup-2-3]
- [nioEventLoopGroup-5-2]

means in netty logs (the numbers). 
Is It something related to threads ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The naming schema is

```
poolName + '-' + poolId.incrementAndGet() + '-' + nextId.incrementAndGet();
```

Where `poolName` is the class, `poolId` is a global counter, and `nextId` is per pool.

So `nioEventLoopGroup-2-2` and `nioEventLoopGroup-2-3` are the 2nd and 3rd thread from the 2nd pool, and `nioEventLoopGroup-5-2` is the 2nd thread from some other pool.

src: https://github.com/netty/netty/blob/4.0/common/src/main/java/io/netty/util/concurrent/DefaultThreadFactory.java#L94